# Meteor simple-todos app - How can I show incomplete task count only for current user?

Tags: meteor

I am working through [this](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) Meteor tutorial and I have updated imports/ui/task.html to only show the tasks to the user who created them as follows:

```
<template name="task">
{{#if isOwner}}
  <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}} {{#if private}}private{{/if}}">
    <button class="delete">&times;</button>

<input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />

  <span class="text">{{text}}</span>

  </li>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

However, I still have the incomplete count showing tasks by all users and I want to change it to just the user who is logged in. This is the part of imports/ui/body.js that I think needs to be changed.

```
Template.body.helpers({
  tasks() {
  const instance = Template.instance();
if (instance.state.get('hideCompleted')) {
  // If hide completed is checked, filter tasks
  return Tasks.find({ checked: { $ne: true } }, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
}
// Otherwise, return all of the tasks
    // Show newest tasks at the top. This is the meat of the thing!
return Tasks.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } });
  },
incompleteCount() {
return Tasks.find({ checked: { $ne: true } }).count();
  },
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please start from reading the help sections, especially: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Do not expect people here to read the tutorial just to understand the problem you are having. Explain the problem in the question. Also, show us what you have tried, not what you think must be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to filter on `ownerId` which is used in this tutorial to associate a task with a user.

```
incompleteCount() {
  return Tasks.find({ ownerId: Meteor.userId(), checked: { $ne: true } }).count();
},
```

Note that when you use multiple criteria like this they are implicitly ANDed.